# Vue-cli webpack wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, webpack, single-page-application, vue-cli

I have a SPA built using VueJS. I am currently looking to integrate this into Wordpress using the Rest API.

I am using the vue-cli webpack setup and of course this injects into the `<div id="app"></div>` inside index.html. So all of this works fine.

What I need to do is take my current project and set this up as a Wordpress theme e.g. have an index.php file which distributes my SPA.

This is where I am struggling. Ideally I would like to have my SPA inside a folder called "app" inside the theme and have an index.php in the root which outputs my "app" directory.

I know this can be done but I am not amazing with Webpack and have been reading all day and searching github for solutions but nothing seems to match my current setup using the Vue-cli.

Has anyone done this before and if so how did you do it? I am aware I may need to change a few settings in my configs but I honestly don't know where to start.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: I'm looking for a similar setup! I found a [WordPress theme starter with Vue.js](https://github.com/rtCamp/VueTheme) and a [WordPress starter plugin with Vue.js](https://github.com/matgargano/vue-wordpress-plugin) but neither of them have hot reloading setup, which makes them fairly useless to me. I'd like to have the fully-robust `vue-cli` webpack (or similar) setup within a page loaded by WordPress so I can access all the localized script variables and other JS that's on the page at run time. Have you found anything since you posted this??

Comment: I know it's a long time that you asked this. So that, have you found any solution to solve this problem. I'm having the same problem for a while and I'm struggling with it. Thanks a lot